# Symbol.iterator is not a function on form element

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, polyfills

I am getting the following error when trying to iterate over a `<form>` element using `for..of` and Babel:

> test[Symbol.iterator] is not a function. (In
>   'testSymbol.iterator', 'test[Symbol.iterator]' is undefined)

I have got the `babel-polyfill` on the page. Iterating over `NodeList`, `Array` and other elements are fine, the problem seems to be the `<form>` element.

The following code works fine in Chrome v49:

```js
for(const x of test) {
console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
</form>
```

However, in a browser which requires polyfilled, I get the error message. Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/207xagv3/) which reproduces the issue.

Which implementation is the correct one? Is this a bug in *babel-polyfill*?

Comment: Mmh, the spec doesn't list that `HTMLFormElement` are iterable (as opposed to `NodeList`s): https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element . But maybe every element that has a getter is iterable by default?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the spec reference. It looks that's the way it's been implemented, but looking at that neither form itself, nor `elements` *should* be iterable.

Comment: However, I remember reading something somewhere about DOM elements and iterables. It could very well be that this is somehow implicitly "specified". I will keep looking...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you.

finally,I solve it like this:

```
const List= document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');
for(let i=0,i<List.length,i++){
   console.log(List.item(i))
}
```

code that go error:

```
 const List= document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');
for(let i of List)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```